# Question whether Convexity-related Inequality Holds

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis

Define

$$
g(a,b) = \frac{b-a}{\sqrt{b+a}}.
$$

I am interested in a generalization of the following inequality

> For any $0 \leq a \leq b \leq c$, one has that
> $$ g(a,c) \leq g(a,b) + g(b,c).$$

This follows from the convexity of $x\mapsto 1/\sqrt{x}$. A proof can be found in Chapter 4 of Le Cam's *Asymptotic Methods in Statistical Decision Theory*.
Furthermore, one can check that the assumption $a \leq b \leq c$ is not needed, as for fixed $c$ the functions $x\mapsto g(x,c)$ and $x\mapsto g(c,x)$ are increasing and decreasing, respectively, which suffices to prove the inequality when $a\leq b\leq c$ does not hold.

The generalization I am interested in is as follows

> For any $x_{00}, x_{01}, x_{10}, x_{11}, x_{20}, x_{21}\geq 0$, one has that
>
> $$g(x_{01}+x_{10}, x_{00}+x_{11}) \leq g(x_{01}+x_{20}, x_{00}+x_{21}) + g(x_{10}+x_{21}, x_{11}+x_{20})$$

There are additional constraints I could give if it would help (namely for any $i\in\{0,1,2\}$, $x_{i0} + x_{i1}\leq 1$), though it is unclear they will be required.
I've tried following the argument of Le Cam, but it seems to break down --- there is a nice simplification that happens in Le Cam's case that does not seem to occur in my generalization.